# Are Nisyonos Lifnei Iver?

Tags: free-will-bechira, lifnei-iver, test, avodath-hashem

How are Nisyonos not considered Lifnei Iver?

One shouldn't place themselves into a Makom Nisayon<sup>1</sup>, and is Chayiv for sinning even if one doesn't sin (such as transgressing by passing a house of immorality). If one can't do this to one's self, then how can *anyone else* do that to them?

Obviously, if Hashem (or perhaps a team of researchers) knows that someone is capable of passing a challenge, then certainly that person shouldn't lose hope, and they should try to win.

Based on the rule of Lifnei Iver, what qualification is being invoked on Heaven's behalf to challenge people, even though they can pass?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Sanhedrin 107a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.107a?lang=bi)</sub>

Comment: This actually has a serious answer.

Comment: For the very reason that @sabba poses – i.e., that this is a legitimate question – I think you should either remove PTIJ and ask this seriously, or make it more Purimdik and ridiculous.